# Where are Doxygen output files put?

Tags: doxygen

I have just run Doxygen from the command line and am unsure where it put it...
It doesn't show up in the directory I ran it from

Is there an easy way to find it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the Doxygen manual:

> The default output directory is the directory in which doxygen is started. The root directory to which the output is written can be changed using the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY. The format specific directory within the output directory can be selected using the HTML_OUTPUT, RTF_OUTPUT, LATEX_OUTPUT, XML_OUTPUT, and MAN_OUTPUT tags of the configuration file. If the output directory does not exist, doxygen will try to create it for you (but it will not try to create a whole path recursively, like mkdir -p does).

If you are having some problems getting it to do what you want use doxywizard it makes writing the configuration file much easier.

Comment: I'm getting it to do stuff just don't know where it put the html file or whatever it uses

Comment: The output depends on what you have configured. If you have configured it to output html it will be a whole directory of html files. Why don't you search your file system for html files created in the last hour.

Comment: So you can't just do: doxygen doxyfile and it give me a file?

Comment: You create a doxyfile and then just do doxygen <doxyfile>. The output will either appear where you specified it in the doxyfile or in the directory in which Doxygen was started. If there isn't anything there perhaps it hasn't worked.